# Count variables from multidimensional array parts

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array with emails

```
$emails = ( "emailid" => array( "email1", "email2" ,"email3" ) );
```

I want to count first part `($emails[])` of multi-dimension array and second part `($emails[][])`. `count($emails)` only counts a whole array.

may be some one knows how.

Thank you!

Comment: `count($emails["emailid"]);` ?

Comment: Confused with the first part and second part of main array.. explain more.

Answer (score 0):

What about this :

```
<?php

$emails = array("emailid" => array("email1","email2","email3"));

echo 'emails[] = ' . count($emails) . '<br />';          // result: 1
echo 'emails["emailid"] = ' . count($emails["emailid"]); // result: 3

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `COUNT_RECURSIVE` flag to change how [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) works and get it to recursively count all items in your array regardless the depth. If you are just looking to get the count of the email addresses within the `emailid` sub array, you can access it directly by it's key.

```
$emails = ['emailid' => ['email1', 'email2', 'email3']];

// recursive count
echo count($emails, COUNT_RECURSIVE); // output 4

// normal count
echo count($emails); // output 1

// normal count using key
echo count($emails['emailid']); // output 3
```